# Calculating energy consumption of TCP in NS2

Tags: c++, tcl, simulation, ns2

I want to simulate energy consumption of TCP in NS2. Can anyone help me regarding this? I'm noob in NS2.

Comment: Do you want the information as the simulation runs or just after the fact?

Comment: As the simulation runs. I have the awk files that would extract energy information from the trace file. I want to know what I have to do in the tcl file to have energy level in trace file.

Answer (score 2):

For getting energy level in trace files,you have to configure nodes with **energymodel** in your tcl script like below,

```
  $ns node-config   -energyModel EnergyModel \
                    -rxPower 0.3 \
                    -txPower 0.6 \
                   -initialEnergy 5 \
```

Comment: I have done this but there is no change in the nam file. How do i generate .tr file from .tcl file such that it contains energy information